# Swagger Open API security Schema giving Object error

Tags: openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-3.0

I am having trouble in setting security schema in open api swagger spec in yaml.

I get below error while setting security schemas:

[image]

in paths I did use Bearerauth but still same issue:

paths:

```
/v1/items:
    get:
      tags:
        - Item Resources
      summary: searches items
      security:
        - BearerAuth: [adsfdf]
      operationId: searchItems
      description: |
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this issue, or there is any issue with implementation ?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out, I have added security globally outside components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your global security definition is indented. Global security is defined at the top level, not inside the auth type or component definitions.

Also, in your path usage, you've defined a scope `adsfdf`. Security scopes do not work with Bearer Authentication - this format is present in OpenAPI for the purpose of OAuth. For more details, see [Swagger's documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/).

```
security:
  - bearerAuth: []         # use the same name as above
```